# What mechanish is used by java.nio.file.Files.copy to copy file to remote server

Tags: java, io, network-programming, nio

I need to know internal mechanism used by java.nio.file.Files.copy to copy a local file to remote server.

Like when we used we doesn't pass any port of remote server, so which port it uses to connect with remote server to copy file contents

Answer (score 2):

The connection to the remote server via java.nio.files is not handled by java, it's handled by the underlying OS, so it is using the port normally used by the OS. In windows for example would be smb port:445.

Although the path syntax  "\ip\path" make looks like java itself is connecting to the remote host, it's passed down for the OS solve and from program perspective it's a local file in the host OS,